# Assignment inside ternary operator

Tags: c++

Is is possible to define a variable inside the first operand of a ternary operator (conditional operator)? A regular if statement can do this,

```
if (int foo = 10)
{
   std::cout << foo;
}
```

Can this be done with a ternary operator?  I imagine it would look something like,

```
std::string result = (int foo = 10; foo > 9 ? "larger than 9" : "less than 10");
```

I'm open to using of libraries like boost if that's the only option

Comment: don't think you can, or should

Comment: @sp2danny Aside from potentially making the code harder to read, I thought this was added in C++17 but I can't find anything on it so I'm now questioning my memory.

Comment: C++17 added `if(<variable definition>; <condition>)`, that may be what you're thinking about. Nothing about such a feature inside conditional operators though.

Comment: @Quentin That is what I was thinking of.

Comment: If you know the value of the `foo`, checking it in a condition doesn't look very sensical. You can capture it in a lamba and immediately invoke it, like: `string ret=[&]{return (foo > 9) ? "g" : "l";}();`

Comment: Similar to @adembudak's suggestion: `std::string result = []{ int foo = 10; return foo > 9 ? "larger than 9" : "less than 10";}();` - if `foo` should depend on some external variable, just capture that by reference (`[&variable]`).

Answer (score 0):

For understanding this, you have to look at the life span of variables within scopes. I'll give you a code snippet to understand this.

```
if (int foo = 10 > 9)
{
    // foo exists here
    cout << foo << endl;    // no error
    cout << "larger than 9" << endl;
}
else
{
    // foo exists here
    cout << foo << endl;    // no error
    cout << "less than 10" << endl;
}


// foo is NOT existing anymore here
string result = (foo > 9 ? "larger than 9" : "less than 10");    // Error
```

So the variable foo in your code would only "live" in the if-conditions.

To understand why C/C++ shows up this behaviour have a look how the Stack is used in C/C++ programs.

Comment: While correct, this doesn't answer OP's question at all. They understand how `if`-scoped variables work, but they're trying to get the same behaviour within a conditional operator.

Answer (score 0):

I think this should have been possible. but unfortunately not possible till now.

with C++ 17 we can do something like this

```
if(int foo = 8; foo > 9)
std::cout << "Hello world";
else
std::cout << foo;
```

ternary operator like
variable = Expression1 ? Expression2 : Expression3

is like short hand for

```
if(Expression1)
{
    variable = Expression2;
}
else
{
    variable = Expression3;
}
```

so assignment inside ternary operator should also have been allowed but it does not work.